# Canvas draw text vertically

Tags: java, android, text, android-canvas, draw

I have put everything I need as I want it to be, my bitmaps, backgrounds and everything, what I need is to draw text that will be vertically shown. Here is my code for now:

```
 private void drawTables(Canvas canvas) {
    for (Table table : mTablesList) {
        float x = mWidht * table.getLeft() / 100;
        float y = mHeight * table.getTop() / 100;
        Rect rect = new Rect();
        rect.set(Math.round(x), Math.round(y), mWidht * table.getRight() / 100, mHeight * table.getBottom() / 100);
        if (table.isAvaliable()) {
            Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.slobodan);
            Bitmap myBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable).getBitmap();
            table.setRect(rect);
            Bitmap nova = getResizedBitmap(myBitmap, 60, 60);
            Rect source = new Rect(0, 0, nova.getWidth(), nova.getHeight());
            table.setSlikaRezervacije(nova);
            canvas.drawBitmap(nova, source, table.getRect(), null);
        } else if (!table.isAvaliable()) {
            Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rezervisan);
            Bitmap myBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable).getBitmap();
            table.setRect(rect);
            Bitmap nova = getResizedBitmap(myBitmap, 60, 60);
            Rect source = new Rect(0, 0, nova.getWidth(), nova.getHeight());
            table.setSlikaRezervacije(nova);
            canvas.drawBitmap(nova, source, table.getRect(), null);
        }

    }}
```

Comment: where's the text variable you want to display? And where exactly do you want to place it? Would it be enough to just rotate the text vertically or do you want to display each character on top of each other? Please be more specific, thx

Comment: Just to rotate text.

Comment: The Canvas class has save, rotate, and restore methods you can use for this purpose.  Have a look at those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need [Paint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html)

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
// your paint settings such as stroke thickness and such
```

Then, rotate your canvas

```
canvas.rotate(yourTextAngle, originX, originY);
```

Then, you draw your text

```
canvas.drawText("Your text", originX, originY, paint);
```

The text should be drawn vertically based on the angle you supplied.

Then if you want to restore the canvas after:

```
canvas.restore();
```

You should check out the information on [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html).  It is very thorough.